# What is this angle calculation rule with $2$ parallel lines?

Tags: geometry, terminology

The rule is that when line n and m are parallel,

$$b=a+c$$

What's the name of this rule? - You won't believe how many books I've checked.

[image: image illustration]

Comment: I’ve never seen a name for this theorem, which is a standard corollary of the main theorem on parallel lines cut by another line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One that comes close is the [exterior angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem#High_school_exterior_angle_theorem) that gives $\,b=a+c\,$ in the construction below:

[image]

Comment: That was what I was thinking too

Comment: and why the angles a abd a-red are equals?

Comment: @gimusi that's called the Z rule

Answer (score 4):

I don’t think there exists a name for this theorem. You can solve it by taking a line parallel to both lines $m$ and $n$, through the vertex of the *crook* between the lines.